# java management clients in trend now

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jakarta-ee, jmx

What are the popular JMX **client** tools for use?
I know about **JConsole** but the problem is, that the managed beans I am trying to configure have as properties `List`s i.e. methods like `setParam(List<String> s);` and JConsole does not allow to set/update properties that are of type list (only see the contents like `[a,b,c]`).
So I am looking for another JMX client to bypass this problem.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) with the [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) agents, you are able to set parameters with string lists/array values (same for arguments of JMX operations). The are given as a comma separated list of string values. It is still somewhat limited now (no escaping), but there is worked underway to fully support any JSON structure as value for writing attributes.

The corresponding clients are [jmx4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl/scripts/jmx4perl) as a command line tool and [j4psh](http://vimeo.com/20215477) a readline based JMX shell with context sensitive command line completion.